# 'make' compiling error in ubuntu

Tags: compiling

I installed ubuntu 14.04 by debootstrap with those packages required for configuring or building a specific package. Everything went well but one thing, it could not build or compile (or configure) some packages especially the linux kernel it just spews up a lots of errors like this :

```
mark@dhcppc0:~/kernel-3.13.7$ make menuconfig
  HOSTCC  scripts/basic/fixdep
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/conf.o
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
make[1]: *** [scripts/kconfig/dochecklxdialog] Error 2
make: *** [menuconfig] Error 2
```

Another one (when I'm compiling ppsspp)

```
mark@dhcppc0:~/ppsspp/build$ make
( test -e Makefile.Native || /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qmake /home/mark/mark's-builds/ppsspp/Qt/Native.pro -o Makefile.Native ) && make -f Makefile.Native 
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
make: *** [sub-Native-pro-make_first-ordered] Error 2
```

**Plus, they have this common line:**

```
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
```

And they all end in `Error 2`

Could someone shed light on this problem?

EDIT:

**I forgot to say that I set the HOME directory to `/home/mark/mark's-builds`**

I got this linux kernel from [here](https://github.com/pfactum/pf-kernel/tree/pf-3.13) and the make file is in [here](https://github.com/pfactum/pf-kernel/blob/pf-3.13/Makefile)

The makefile for ppsspp is:

```
#############################################################################
# Makefile for building: PPSSPPQt
# Generated by qmake (3.0) (Qt 5.2.1)
# Project:  ../Qt/PPSSPPQt.pro
# Template: subdirs
# Command: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qmake -o Makefile ../Qt/PPSSPPQt.pro
#############################################################################

MAKEFILE      = Makefile

first: make_first
QMAKE         = /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qmake
DEL_FILE      = rm -f
CHK_DIR_EXISTS= test -d
MKDIR         = mkdir -p
COPY          = cp -f
COPY_FILE     = cp -f
COPY_DIR      = cp -f -R
INSTALL_FILE  = install -m 644 -p
INSTALL_PROGRAM = install -m 755 -p
INSTALL_DIR   = $(COPY_DIR)
DEL_FILE      = rm -f
SYMLINK       = ln -f -s
DEL_DIR       = rmdir
MOVE          = mv -f
SUBTARGETS    =  \
        sub-Native-pro \
        sub-Core-pro \
        sub-Common-pro \
        sub-PPSSPP-pro


sub-Native-pro-qmake_all:  FORCE
    $(QMAKE) /home/mark/mark's-builds/ppsspp/Qt/Native.pro -o Makefile.Native
    $(MAKE) -f Makefile.Native qmake_all
sub-Native-pro: FORCE
    ( test -e Makefile.Native || $(QMAKE) /home/mark/mark's-builds/ppsspp/Qt/Native.pro -o Makefile.Native ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile.Native
sub-Native-pro-make_first-ordered: FORCE
    ( test -e Makefile.Native || $(QMAKE) /home/mark/mark's-builds/ppsspp/Qt/Native.pro -o Makefile.Native ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile.Native 
sub-Native-pro-make_first: FORCE
    ( test -e Makefile.Native || $(QMAKE) /home/mark/mark's-builds/ppsspp/Qt/Native.pro -o Makefile.Native ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile.Native 
sub-Native-pro-all-ordered: FORCE
    ( test -e Makefile.Native || $(QMAKE) /home/mark/mark's-builds/ppsspp/Qt/Native.pro -o Makefile.Native ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile.Native all
sub-Native-pro-all: FORCE
    ( test -e Makefile.Native || $(QMAKE) /home/mark/mark's-builds/ppsspp/Qt/Native.pro -o Makefile.Native ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile.Native all
sub-Native-pro-clean-ordered: FORCE
    ( test -e Makefile.Native || $(QMAKE) /home/mark/mark's-builds/ppsspp/Qt/Native.pro -o Makefile.Native ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile.Native clean
sub-Native-pro-clean: FORCE
    ( test -e Makefile.Native || $(QMAKE) /home/mark/mark's-builds/ppsspp/Qt/Native.pro -o Makefile.Native ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile.Native clean
sub-Native-pro-distclean-ordered: FORCE
    ( test -e Makefile.Native || $(QMAKE) /home/mark/mark's-builds/ppsspp/Qt/Native.pro -o Makefile.Native ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile.Native distclean
sub-Native-pro-distclean: FORCE
    ( test -e Makefile.Native || $(QMAKE) /home/mark/mark's-builds/ppsspp/Qt/Native.pro -o Makefile.Native ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile.Native distclean
sub-Native-pro-install_subtargets-ordered: FORCE
    ( test -e Makefile.Native || $(QMAKE) /home/mark/mark's-builds/ppsspp/Qt/Native.pro -o Makefile.Native ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile.Native install
sub-Native-pro-install_subtargets: FORCE
    ( test -e Makefile.Native || $(QMAKE) /home/mark/mark's-builds/ppsspp/Qt/Native.pro -o Makefile.Native ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile.Native install
sub-Native-pro-uninstall_subtargets-ordered: FORCE
    ( test -e Makefile.Native || $(QMAKE) /home/mark/mark's-builds/ppsspp/Qt/Native.pro -o Makefile.Native ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile.Native uninstall
sub-Native-pro-uninstall_subtargets: FORCE
    ( test -e Makefile.Native || $(QMAKE) /home/mark/mark's-builds/ppsspp/Qt/Native.pro -o Makefile.Native ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile.Native uninstall
sub-Core-pro-qmake_all: sub-Native-pro-qmake_all FORCE
    $(QMAKE) /home/mark/mark's-builds/ppsspp/Qt/Core.pro -o Makefile.Core
    $(MAKE) -f Makefile.Core qmake_all
sub-Core-pro: FORCE
    ( test -e Makefile.Core || $(QMAKE) /home/mark/mark's-builds/ppsspp/Qt/Core.pro -o Makefile.Core ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile.Core
sub-Core-pro-make_first-ordered: sub-Native-pro-make_first-ordered  FORCE
    ( test -e Makefile.Core || $(QMAKE) /home/mark/mark's-builds/ppsspp/Qt/Core.pro -o Makefile.Core ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile.Core 
sub-Core-pro-make_first: FORCE
    ( test -e Makefile.Core || $(QMAKE) /home/mark/mark's-builds/ppsspp/Qt/Core.pro -o Makefile.Core ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile.Core 
sub-Core-pro-all-ordered: sub-Native-pro-all-ordered  FORCE
    ( test -e Makefile.Core || $(QMAKE) /home/mark/mark's-builds/ppsspp/Qt/Core.pro -o Makefile.Core ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile.Core all
sub-Core-pro-all: FORCE
    ( test -e Makefile.Core || $(QMAKE) /home/mark/mark's-builds/ppsspp/Qt/Core.pro -o Makefile.Core ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile.Core all
sub-Core-pro-clean-ordered: sub-Native-pro-clean-ordered  FORCE
    ( test -e Makefile.Core || $(QMAKE) /home/mark/mark's-builds/ppsspp/Qt/Core.pro -o Makefile.Core ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile.Core clean
sub-Core-pro-clean: FORCE
    ( test -e Makefile.Core || $(QMAKE) /home/mark/mark's-builds/ppsspp/Qt/Core.pro -o Makefile.Core ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile.Core clean
sub-Core-pro-distclean-ordered: sub-Native-pro-distclean-ordered  FORCE
    ( test -e Makefile.Core || $(QMAKE) /home/mark/mark's-builds/ppsspp/Qt/Core.pro -o Makefile.Core ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile.Core distclean
sub-Core-pro-distclean: FORCE
    ( test -e Makefile.Core || $(QMAKE) /home/mark/mark's-builds/ppsspp/Qt/Core.pro -o Makefile.Core ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile.Core distclean
sub-Core-pro-install_subtargets-ordered: sub-Native-pro-install_subtargets-ordered  FORCE
    ( test -e Makefile.Core || $(QMAKE) /home/mark/mark's-builds/ppsspp/Qt/Core.pro -o Makefile.Core ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile.Core install
sub-Core-pro-install_subtargets: FORCE
    ( test -e Makefile.Core || $(QMAKE) /home/mark/mark's-builds/ppsspp/Qt/Core.pro -o Makefile.Core ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile.Core install
sub-Core-pro-uninstall_subtargets-ordered: sub-Native-pro-uninstall_subtargets-ordered  FORCE
    ( test -e Makefile.Core || $(QMAKE) /home/mark/mark's-builds/ppsspp/Qt/Core.pro -o Makefile.Core ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile.Core uninstall
sub-Core-pro-uninstall_subtargets: FORCE
    ( test -e Makefile.Core || $(QMAKE) /home/mark/mark's-builds/ppsspp/Qt/Core.pro -o Makefile.Core ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile.Core uninstall
sub-Common-pro-qmake_all: sub-Core-pro-qmake_all FORCE
    $(QMAKE) /home/mark/mark's-builds/ppsspp/Qt/Common.pro -o Makefile.Common
    $(MAKE) -f Makefile.Common qmake_all
sub-Common-pro: FORCE
    ( test -e Makefile.Common || $(QMAKE) /home/mark/mark's-builds/ppsspp/Qt/Common.pro -o Makefile.Common ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile.Common
sub-Common-pro-make_first-ordered: sub-Core-pro-make_first-ordered  FORCE
    ( test -e Makefile.Common || $(QMAKE) /home/mark/mark's-builds/ppsspp/Qt/Common.pro -o Makefile.Common ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile.Common 
sub-Common-pro-make_first: FORCE
    ( test -e Makefile.Common || $(QMAKE) /home/mark/mark's-builds/ppsspp/Qt/Common.pro -o Makefile.Common ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile.Common 
sub-Common-pro-all-ordered: sub-Core-pro-all-ordered  FORCE
    ( test -e Makefile.Common || $(QMAKE) /home/mark/mark's-builds/ppsspp/Qt/Common.pro -o Makefile.Common ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile.Common all
sub-Common-pro-all: FORCE
    ( test -e Makefile.Common || $(QMAKE) /home/mark/mark's-builds/ppsspp/Qt/Common.pro -o Makefile.Common ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile.Common all
sub-Common-pro-clean-ordered: sub-Core-pro-clean-ordered  FORCE
    ( test -e Makefile.Common || $(QMAKE) /home/mark/mark's-builds/ppsspp/Qt/Common.pro -o Makefile.Common ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile.Common clean
sub-Common-pro-clean: FORCE
    ( test -e Makefile.Common || $(QMAKE) /home/mark/mark's-builds/ppsspp/Qt/Common.pro -o Makefile.Common ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile.Common clean
sub-Common-pro-distclean-ordered: sub-Core-pro-distclean-ordered  FORCE
    ( test -e Makefile.Common || $(QMAKE) /home/mark/mark's-builds/ppsspp/Qt/Common.pro -o Makefile.Common ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile.Common distclean
sub-Common-pro-distclean: FORCE
    ( test -e Makefile.Common || $(QMAKE) /home/mark/mark's-builds/ppsspp/Qt/Common.pro -o Makefile.Common ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile.Common distclean
sub-Common-pro-install_subtargets-ordered: sub-Core-pro-install_subtargets-ordered  FORCE
    ( test -e Makefile.Common || $(QMAKE) /home/mark/mark's-builds/ppsspp/Qt/Common.pro -o Makefile.Common ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile.Common install
sub-Common-pro-install_subtargets: FORCE
    ( test -e Makefile.Common || $(QMAKE) /home/mark/mark's-builds/ppsspp/Qt/Common.pro -o Makefile.Common ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile.Common install
sub-Common-pro-uninstall_subtargets-ordered: sub-Core-pro-uninstall_subtargets-ordered  FORCE
    ( test -e Makefile.Common || $(QMAKE) /home/mark/mark's-builds/ppsspp/Qt/Common.pro -o Makefile.Common ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile.Common uninstall
sub-Common-pro-uninstall_subtargets: FORCE
    ( test -e Makefile.Common || $(QMAKE) /home/mark/mark's-builds/ppsspp/Qt/Common.pro -o Makefile.Common ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile.Common uninstall
sub-PPSSPP-pro-qmake_all: sub-Common-pro-qmake_all FORCE
    $(QMAKE) /home/mark/mark's-builds/ppsspp/Qt/PPSSPP.pro -o Makefile.PPSSPP
    $(MAKE) -f Makefile.PPSSPP qmake_all
sub-PPSSPP-pro: FORCE
    ( test -e Makefile.PPSSPP || $(QMAKE) /home/mark/mark's-builds/ppsspp/Qt/PPSSPP.pro -o Makefile.PPSSPP ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile.PPSSPP
sub-PPSSPP-pro-make_first-ordered: sub-Common-pro-make_first-ordered  FORCE
    ( test -e Makefile.PPSSPP || $(QMAKE) /home/mark/mark's-builds/ppsspp/Qt/PPSSPP.pro -o Makefile.PPSSPP ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile.PPSSPP 
sub-PPSSPP-pro-make_first: FORCE
    ( test -e Makefile.PPSSPP || $(QMAKE) /home/mark/mark's-builds/ppsspp/Qt/PPSSPP.pro -o Makefile.PPSSPP ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile.PPSSPP 
sub-PPSSPP-pro-all-ordered: sub-Common-pro-all-ordered  FORCE
    ( test -e Makefile.PPSSPP || $(QMAKE) /home/mark/mark's-builds/ppsspp/Qt/PPSSPP.pro -o Makefile.PPSSPP ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile.PPSSPP all
sub-PPSSPP-pro-all: FORCE
    ( test -e Makefile.PPSSPP || $(QMAKE) /home/mark/mark's-builds/ppsspp/Qt/PPSSPP.pro -o Makefile.PPSSPP ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile.PPSSPP all
sub-PPSSPP-pro-clean-ordered: sub-Common-pro-clean-ordered  FORCE
    ( test -e Makefile.PPSSPP || $(QMAKE) /home/mark/mark's-builds/ppsspp/Qt/PPSSPP.pro -o Makefile.PPSSPP ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile.PPSSPP clean
sub-PPSSPP-pro-clean: FORCE
    ( test -e Makefile.PPSSPP || $(QMAKE) /home/mark/mark's-builds/ppsspp/Qt/PPSSPP.pro -o Makefile.PPSSPP ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile.PPSSPP clean
sub-PPSSPP-pro-distclean-ordered: sub-Common-pro-distclean-ordered  FORCE
    ( test -e Makefile.PPSSPP || $(QMAKE) /home/mark/mark's-builds/ppsspp/Qt/PPSSPP.pro -o Makefile.PPSSPP ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile.PPSSPP distclean
sub-PPSSPP-pro-distclean: FORCE
    ( test -e Makefile.PPSSPP || $(QMAKE) /home/mark/mark's-builds/ppsspp/Qt/PPSSPP.pro -o Makefile.PPSSPP ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile.PPSSPP distclean
sub-PPSSPP-pro-install_subtargets-ordered: sub-Common-pro-install_subtargets-ordered  FORCE
    ( test -e Makefile.PPSSPP || $(QMAKE) /home/mark/mark's-builds/ppsspp/Qt/PPSSPP.pro -o Makefile.PPSSPP ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile.PPSSPP install
sub-PPSSPP-pro-install_subtargets: FORCE
    ( test -e Makefile.PPSSPP || $(QMAKE) /home/mark/mark's-builds/ppsspp/Qt/PPSSPP.pro -o Makefile.PPSSPP ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile.PPSSPP install
sub-PPSSPP-pro-uninstall_subtargets-ordered: sub-Common-pro-uninstall_subtargets-ordered  FORCE
    ( test -e Makefile.PPSSPP || $(QMAKE) /home/mark/mark's-builds/ppsspp/Qt/PPSSPP.pro -o Makefile.PPSSPP ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile.PPSSPP uninstall
sub-PPSSPP-pro-uninstall_subtargets: FORCE
    ( test -e Makefile.PPSSPP || $(QMAKE) /home/mark/mark's-builds/ppsspp/Qt/PPSSPP.pro -o Makefile.PPSSPP ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile.PPSSPP uninstall

Makefile: ../Qt/PPSSPPQt.pro /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++/qmake.conf /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/features/spec_pre.prf \
        /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/common/shell-unix.conf \
        /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/common/unix.conf \
        /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/common/linux.conf \
        /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/common/gcc-base.conf \
        /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/common/gcc-base-unix.conf \
        /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/common/g++-base.conf \
        /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/common/g++-unix.conf \
        /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/qconfig.pri \
        /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_bootstrap_private.pri \
        /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_concurrent.pri \
        /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_concurrent_private.pri \
        /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_core.pri \
        /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_core_private.pri \
        /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_dbus.pri \
        /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_dbus_private.pri \
        /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_gui.pri \
        /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_gui_private.pri \
        /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_network.pri \
        /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_network_private.pri \
        /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_opengl.pri \
        /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_opengl_private.pri \
        /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_openglextensions.pri \
        /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_openglextensions_private.pri \
        /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_platformsupport_private.pri \
        /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_printsupport.pri \
        /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_printsupport_private.pri \
        /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_qml.pri \
        /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_qmltest.pri \
        /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_quick.pri \
        /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_sql.pri \
        /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_sql_private.pri \
        /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_testlib.pri \
        /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_testlib_private.pri \
        /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_widgets.pri \
        /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_widgets_private.pri \
        /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_xml.pri \
        /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_xml_private.pri \
        /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/features/qt_functions.prf \
        /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/features/qt_config.prf \
        /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++/qmake.conf \
        /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/features/spec_post.prf \
        /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/features/exclusive_builds.prf \
        /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/features/default_pre.prf \
        /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/features/resolve_config.prf \
        /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/features/default_post.prf \
        /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/features/unix/gdb_dwarf_index.prf \
        /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/features/warn_on.prf \
        /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/features/testcase_targets.prf \
        /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/features/exceptions.prf \
        /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/features/yacc.prf \
        /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/features/lex.prf \
        ../Qt/PPSSPPQt.pro
    $(QMAKE) -o Makefile ../Qt/PPSSPPQt.pro
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/features/spec_pre.prf:
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/common/shell-unix.conf:
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/common/unix.conf:
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/common/linux.conf:
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/common/gcc-base.conf:
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/common/gcc-base-unix.conf:
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/common/g++-base.conf:
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/common/g++-unix.conf:
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/qconfig.pri:
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_bootstrap_private.pri:
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_concurrent.pri:
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_concurrent_private.pri:
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_core.pri:
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_core_private.pri:
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_dbus.pri:
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_dbus_private.pri:
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_gui.pri:
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_gui_private.pri:
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_network.pri:
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_network_private.pri:
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_opengl.pri:
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_opengl_private.pri:
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_openglextensions.pri:
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_openglextensions_private.pri:
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_platformsupport_private.pri:
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_printsupport.pri:
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_printsupport_private.pri:
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_qml.pri:
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_qmltest.pri:
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_quick.pri:
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_sql.pri:
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_sql_private.pri:
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_testlib.pri:
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_testlib_private.pri:
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_widgets.pri:
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_widgets_private.pri:
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_xml.pri:
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_xml_private.pri:
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/features/qt_functions.prf:
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/features/qt_config.prf:
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++/qmake.conf:
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/features/spec_post.prf:
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/features/exclusive_builds.prf:
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/features/default_pre.prf:
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/features/resolve_config.prf:
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/features/default_post.prf:
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/features/unix/gdb_dwarf_index.prf:
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/features/warn_on.prf:
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/features/testcase_targets.prf:
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/features/exceptions.prf:
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/features/yacc.prf:
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/features/lex.prf:
../Qt/PPSSPPQt.pro:
qmake: FORCE
    @$(QMAKE) -o Makefile ../Qt/PPSSPPQt.pro

qmake_all: sub-Native-pro-qmake_all sub-Core-pro-qmake_all sub-Common-pro-qmake_all sub-PPSSPP-pro-qmake_all FORCE

make_first: sub-Native-pro-make_first-ordered sub-Core-pro-make_first-ordered sub-Common-pro-make_first-ordered sub-PPSSPP-pro-make_first-ordered FORCE
all: sub-Native-pro-all-ordered sub-Core-pro-all-ordered sub-Common-pro-all-ordered sub-PPSSPP-pro-all-ordered FORCE
clean: sub-Native-pro-clean-ordered sub-Core-pro-clean-ordered sub-Common-pro-clean-ordered sub-PPSSPP-pro-clean-ordered FORCE
distclean: sub-Native-pro-distclean-ordered sub-Core-pro-distclean-ordered sub-Common-pro-distclean-ordered sub-PPSSPP-pro-distclean-ordered FORCE
    -$(DEL_FILE) Makefile
install_subtargets: sub-Native-pro-install_subtargets-ordered sub-Core-pro-install_subtargets-ordered sub-Common-pro-install_subtargets-ordered sub-PPSSPP-pro-install_subtargets-ordered FORCE
uninstall_subtargets: sub-Native-pro-uninstall_subtargets-ordered sub-Core-pro-uninstall_subtargets-ordered sub-Common-pro-uninstall_subtargets-ordered sub-PPSSPP-pro-uninstall_subtargets-ordered FORCE

sub-Native-pro-check_ordered:
    ( test -e Makefile.Native || $(QMAKE) /home/mark/mark's-builds/ppsspp/Qt/Native.pro -o Makefile.Native ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile.Native check
sub-Core-pro-check_ordered: sub-Native-pro-check_ordered 
    ( test -e Makefile.Core || $(QMAKE) /home/mark/mark's-builds/ppsspp/Qt/Core.pro -o Makefile.Core ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile.Core check
sub-Common-pro-check_ordered: sub-Core-pro-check_ordered 
    ( test -e Makefile.Common || $(QMAKE) /home/mark/mark's-builds/ppsspp/Qt/Common.pro -o Makefile.Common ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile.Common check
sub-PPSSPP-pro-check_ordered: sub-Common-pro-check_ordered 
    ( test -e Makefile.PPSSPP || $(QMAKE) /home/mark/mark's-builds/ppsspp/Qt/PPSSPP.pro -o Makefile.PPSSPP ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile.PPSSPP check
check: sub-Native-pro-check_ordered sub-Core-pro-check_ordered sub-Common-pro-check_ordered sub-PPSSPP-pro-check_ordered
install: install_subtargets  FORCE

uninstall:  uninstall_subtargets FORCE

FORCE:
```

Comment: Could you add the makefile to your question?

Comment: Sure, @the_Seppi.

Comment: Also, my friend said that I shouldn't put that `'` symbol, it may cause compilcations in determining the absolute path of the files during the compilation that may eventually lead to an error. I don't know if that is the cause.

Comment: Didn't see this. I assume this is the error because it says unterminated string. The compiler may interpret it as a string initialiser and quits because it can't find the end of the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you want to compile? There are easiest, safest ways to get the program:

### Avoid compiling

1) **Download and install the .deb package**. To do that, paste this line:

for 32 bits:

```
wget -O ppsspp.deb http://goo.gl/viQzcU && sudo dpkg -i ppsspp.deb ; sudo apt-get -f install -y ; rm ppsspp.deb
```

for 64 bits:

```
wget -O ppsspp.deb http://goo.gl/OHHDs1 && sudo dpkg -i ppsspp.deb ; sudo apt-get -f install -y ; rm ppsspp.deb
```

or 2) **install the program through a ppa**. You can install it using Noobslab PPA. The repo is Trusty compatible. The only restrictiction is that it has a lot of things and (for some reason) you might want to avoid to be updated in that programs too. If you don't have problems with that, the PPA is the best alternative cause it will upgrade you to the latest version (`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`). If you want to install *just ppsspp*, then probably the option above may fit better. The list of the additional programs that **will be updated** (not instaled though, if you didn't had it installed previously) can be found here: https://launchpad.net/~noobslab/+archive/apps?field.series_filter=trusty

Add the PPA by:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:noobslab/apps 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ppsspp -y
```

Source: http://www.noobslab.com/2014/02/ppsspp-psp-emulator-available-for.html

### Compiling

**If you still want to compile...** Have you tried this?
Locate yourself in a new folder (not that ppsspp you created and try this line by line):

```
git clone git://github.com/hrydgard/ppsspp.git && cd ppsspp
git submodule update -i
./b.sh
cd build
./PPSSPPSDL
```

Note that you must have the git package installed (`sudo apt-get install git`) . That above is in the discussion forum on how to compile the program. http://forums.ppsspp.org/showthread.php?tid=1298